# isotope container - show on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-isotope

I'm using isotope to create a filter feature. But the entire isotope container needs to be hidden on the initial page load, and visitor will have to click on a button for the container to show.

I have the filter working, but when you click on the button, the first time the container loads, all items are on top of each other, then when you click on either one of the filters, everything falls into place.

You can see my code here - http://chrsdev.com/test.html

How can I fix the issue of all items positioning on top of each other on the initial content load?

Would greatly appreciate it if someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download [imagesloaded.js](http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js) and add the script to your page. (Unloaded images can throw off Isotope layouts and cause item elements to overlap. imagesLoaded resolves this issue)

Then call isotope like this:

```
//Initialize isotope on each container
    jQuery.each($container, function (j) {
     this.imagesLoaded( function() {
        this.isotope({
            itemSelector : '.element-item'
        });
   });
    });
```

ADDENDUM

The issue is with your each function and "this". Try this instead.

```
  //Initialize isotope on each container
    jQuery.each($container, function (j) {
     $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
        $container.isotope({
            itemSelector : '.element-item'
        });
   });
    });
```

Comment: Hi Macsupport, your suggestion definitely fixed the load issue I was having, but now the filter feature stopped working. when you click on any of the filters nothing comes up.

Comment: Hi Macsupport, i had to edit a bit of the HTML code as well... but you're edits definitely pointed me to the right direction. Thank you very much.